# Problem with implenting Uploadify with Wordpress

Tags: admin, uploads

Trying to get Uploadify to work together with Wordpress.
I've implented the code from documentation in a metabox in wordpress admin area.

I can "select file" and upload it, and Uploadify will show progress, but when I check the destination folder, it's empty.
The folder has chmod 777 so I don't understand what could be wrong..

All help appreciated.

```
<link href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/uploadify/uploadify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/uploadify/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
'uploader' : '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
'script' : '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/uploadify/uploadify.php',
'cancelImg' : '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/uploadify/cancel.png',
'folder' : '<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-content/uploads',
'auto' : true
});
});
</script>

<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />
```

Uploadify.php

```
<?php
/*
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // $fileTypes  = str_replace('*.','',$_REQUEST['fileext']);
    // $fileTypes  = str_replace(';','|',$fileTypes);
    // $typesArray = split('\|',$fileTypes);
    // $fileParts  = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    // if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$typesArray)) {
        // Uncomment the following line if you want to make the directory if it doesn't exist
        // mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0755, true);

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);
    // } else {
    //  echo 'Invalid file type.';
    // }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please provide the PHP code as well.

Comment: Updated. It's the standard uploadify.php that comes with the install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your uploadify.php is all inside a comment so its not really saving the file.

change it with this:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    $fileTypes  = str_replace('*.','',$_REQUEST['fileext']);
    $fileTypes  = str_replace(';','|',$fileTypes);
    $typesArray = split('\|',$fileTypes);
    $fileParts  = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$typesArray)) {
        // Uncomment the following line if you want to make the directory if it doesn't exist
        // mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0755, true);

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
?>
```

and also make sure you validate the file type because i had a site hacked after a hacker uploaded a php shell script with uploadify.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize, thought it was all optional. It didn't change anything however, still not uploading although it shows full progress and "completed"

Comment: @INT: the full progress and "completed" you are seeing is the file gets sent to the server but noting is done with it so its not saved.

Comment: I meant: I replaced the code in my uploadify.php with the one you pasted above. And still it doesn't save the image. Wasn't the code you pasted supposed to make it save the upload? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @INT: you need to specify  file types for example: `'fileExt'     : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png', `

Comment: Thank you for your patience @Bainternet, but I'm still not able to get any images uploaded to the server. This is what I've got so far: http://pastie.org/1697539 / http://pastie.org/1697537 and as I previously mentioned, the uploads folder is chmodded to 777 to avoid any troubles with permissions.

Comment: @INT: change your code with this http://pastie.org/1697617

Comment: @Bainternet: Finally it works, thanks alot! Any ideas why the way I did it didn't work?

Comment: @INT: the problem was with the` folder` you defined it as url and it needs to be a path. Make sure you add some server side validation of file types to avoid hacking.

Comment: Absolutely, it won't be available publicly though. Just gonna use it in the admin area. Thanks alot again!

Comment: Glad i can help.